# Write to double const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

I want to implement my own string implementation for education. For that I defined a struct named string as follows:

```
struct string {
    const char *const data;
    const int length;
};
```

I use functions to create these string structs and then I assign them to variables.

In order to override the `const int length` I use the following trick:

```
*(int *) &result.length = // a int
```

Now I also want to write to the `const char *const data`.
As far as I know the first `const` makes sure that you cant edit the items at which the pointer points, and the  second `const` is that you can't point the pointer to a different memory location. These are properties of an immutable string. So my question is: How can I assign something to the `const char *const data` like I did to the `const int length`?

Edit: `result` as shown above is an instance of the struct `string`

Comment: Wait. Why would you make all the members `const` and then violate their constness?

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar I only violate it when I create the string. after it is created, it should not be changed (hence the consts)

Comment: Why not make the type opaque, so that users cannot delve inside the structure, and hence cannot modify it except using the access functions you provide.  When you add that many `const` qualifiers, you make the structure unmodifiable, with the dire consequences that you have to ask questions on SO.  What you're doing is not good; the fact that you're abusing casts to make it work is an indication that what you're doing is not good.

Comment: You can initialize your struct with `struct string myString = { "this is my string", strlen("this is my string") };` Then you won't be able to modify it, which is the whole point of `const`...

Comment: @yano yes this did it thanks.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Inside a function, an automatically allocated structure can be initialized with function calls.  Outside a function (file scope), or inside a function with `static` duration, you can't use a function call to initialize the variable.  You can't initialize dynamically allocated memory; you have to assign to it.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar That was meant to be more pseudo-code,, but it does compile and print correctly for me. I assume the compiler must be optimizing `strlen` into a constant. But since that field is meant to be a constant anyway, some kind of `#define` or magic number could work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I was thinking about file scope, hence the comment, but then realised what you're saying and removed it before you had a chance to reply. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanB : Have a look into opaque types per Jonathan's suggestion, which - I believe - are the actual solution to what you want to achieve. If just using initialisers this way works for you, then great, but be aware of the limitations that they have.

Comment: `*(int *) &result.length = // a int` That isn't a "trick" it is an abomination

Comment: Given that `*(int *) &result.length = 14;` "works", so should `*(char **)&result.data = "Do not do this";`.  It is irredeemably nasty, but it should work.

Comment: @yano You can write an answer.

Comment: @MCG well I was away for a few hours there and chux beat me to it. That's a better answer anyway, although I think the _real_ answer here is to switch to `c++` and write a `std::string` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the `struct string` at its declaration and *initialize* it.

Also recommend to store the *size* and not the *length* and use `size_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct string {
  const char * const data;
  const size_t size;
};

struct string string_copy(const char *src) {
  size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
  char *copy = malloc(size);
  if (copy) {
    memcpy(copy, src, size);
  } else {
    size = 0;
  }

  struct string retval = {copy, size}; // ****
  return retval;

  // or return a compound literal (C99)
  return (struct string){ copy, size};
}

void string_free(struct string s) {
  free((void*)s.data);
}

int main(void) {
  struct string a = string_copy("Hello");
  printf("%zu <%s>\n", a.size, a.data);
  string_free(a); 
  // do not use `a` subsequently
  return 0;
}
```

I do not recommend to initialize with a *string literal* like `struct string retval = {"World", 6};` as that limits the usefulness of `struct string`.

Using a opaque `struct` has many advantages [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064521/write-to-double-const-pointer/46066330#comment79090074_46064521) that exceed this approach - mainly to keep other code from messing with the `struct string`.